# How to check the presence of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization attributes in an IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData>?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am working with a third-party library that provides a list of custom attribute data in the form of an `IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData>`. These attributes come from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` namespace, such as `AllowAnonymous`, `Authorize`, and `Authorize(Roles = "admin")`. Currently, I am checking for the existence of the `AllowAnonymous` attribute by comparing the `FullName` of the attribute against a hardcoded string:

```
if (CustomAttributes.Any(item => item.AttributeType.FullName == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymousAttribute"))
{
    //method decorated with [AllowAnonymous]
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm hoping to avoid hardcoding the attribute names in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `typeof` to compare the types will get rid of the hardcoded string:

```
if (CustomAttributes.Any(item => item.AttributeType == typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymousAttribute)))
{
    //method decorated with [AllowAnonymous]
}
```